# Strange jquery/html behaivior with newer versions of chrome

Tags: jquery, html, google-chrome

I just came across a strange bug i have some jQuery that changes the text within a span element with `jQuery(".price-box .price").html("$4.25&nbsp;")`, in the latest versions of chrome it started doing somthing wierd like this

[image]

this didn't used to happen and still doesn't happen on other browsers can someone please give me some insight into whats going on? also if after this is triggered i put that line into my console only one of the two strings in the element changes the other one stays as is?

Comment: What version of Chrome are you using ? Also can you provide all relevant code if possible a snippet or a fiddle would be helpful.

Comment: 57, this is in a `jQuery(".product-shop .alt-price").bind("DOMSubtreeModified", function() {}` i am mainly baffeled by the two strings as text in one html element thing

Comment: I think the issue is being caused by your event `DOMSubtreeModified`. Changing the DOM from within the event handler should be it. Try executing the `html()` from outside the event and see if the issue persists.

Comment: Can you provide a snippet or a fiddle.

Comment: ok I successfully circumvented it by adding set-timeout i guess i will leave it at that thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue is being caused by your event `DOMSubtreeModified`. Changing the DOM from within the event handler should be triggering it again. Try executing the `html()` from outside the event and see if the issue persists.